# How can I put this display SSD1306 to sleep?

Tags: display, sleep

I have built a kitchen timer and it is supposed to spend most of its life in sleep mode in order to save power. I am using the SSD1306Ascii library (SPI) by William Greiman.

In this library I have found hints to power on and off commands but I don't know how to use them:

```
/** Set Display off. */
#define SSD1306_DISPLAYOFF 0xAE
/** Set Display on. */
#define SSD1306_DISPLAYON 0xAF
```

From what I could gather from the web, I need to re-initialize the display after turning it off and on again. But before I take care of that (which should be simple as it is done in setup anyway) I need to find out how to use these commands.

Would you help out a rookie?

Comment: So doing `oled.ssd1306WriteCmd(0xAE);` had no effect?

Comment: Can you post a link to the data sheet/instructions for the display?

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt It does have aneffect. Even the desirred one. But until you mentioned it I did not know how to use it. I did not stumble upon ssd1306WriteCmd in the documentation - or upon example to be precise. Thank you!